# Remember password for third box

Tags: html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I am developing the Website which allows the user to save the login credentials in browser.Login page contain three input fields,normally two field only save in the browser.what should i do for saving the third input field also ?? I have tried giving input type as password,its not working.

[image]

Comment: You might reconsider why you need password **and** PIN. Can you simply concatenate both?

Comment: Do you mean to save the stuff with the built-in password manager?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your security requirements, you could persist it in a cookie.

For example, saving it would be something like this (using [jQuery](https://www.sitepoint.com/eat-those-cookies-with-jquery/)):

```
$("#pinField").on('change',function() {
   var pin = $("#pinField").val(),
   $.cookie('pin', pin);
});
```

Comment: Nick, i need to save PIN input field like UserName and Password in browser.so that user can login while visiting website again.cookie will not help.

Comment: That's not possible. If you don't make it a password field it can be auto-filled, but I don't believe Chrome can save and restore more than one password per login page. So the next best thing is a cookie, where you can fill in the field automatically and have chrome fill the username and password from its password manager.